# SyntaxError: invalid syntax. > def isUF2(buf)

Tags: python

Problem with line of code, Syntax Error. Line |def isUF2(buf)|.

Python file is to convert bin file to a uf2 file.

cmd code done in file directory|python(2 and 3 were tested) pythonfile.py binfile.bin|

error that pops up
 File "pythonfile.py", line 19
    def isUF2(buf)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Code:**

```
appstartaddr = 0x2000

def isUF2(buf)

    w = struct.unpack(II, buf[08])

    return w[0] == UF2_MAGIC_START0 and w[1] == UF2_MAGIC_START1
```

I kept getting the error using python 2.7 and python 3.x.

The result of this code (the hole file) is to convert a file (.bin to .uf2)

Comment: You forgot the colon. It should be `def isUF2(buf):`

Answer (score 0):

**Correct syntax:**

```
appstartaddr = 0x2000

def isUF2(buf): # ":" cause error!

    w = struct.unpack(II, buf[08])

    return w[0] == UF2_MAGIC_START0 and w[1] == UF2_MAGIC_START1
```